# EasyMock object for unit testing involving scope="request" bean

Tags: spring, junit, request, easymock

I am trying to add some Unit Testing to some of our companies code.  Yes, I know it should already be there, but not everyone seems to have the same view of unit testing that I do.

However, I have come against a bit of a stopper for me.  Admittedly, my Java, Spring and Unit Testing knowledge are not all that they should be.  My problem is this though:

I have added a unit test to my code, which tests a class.  This class includes a bean which has scope="request", and when it tries to instantiate the bean it throws an exception:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope 'request'`

I believe this is because I don't have a HttpServletRequest object, but I don't know how to create a mock one of these and also I don't know how, once created, to add this Mock Object to the unit test so that it resolves this problem.

Below is a cut down version of the code involved, which I believe includes all of the details that are part of this problem.

How can I get this to work?

```
@Test
public void handleRequest() {
    try {
        Message<?> outMessage = (Message<?>) response.handleRequest(map);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        assertNotNull(e);
    }
    outMessage.getPayload().toString());
}

public class upddResponse extends AbstractResponseTransform {

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Message<?> handleRequest(Map<String, Message<?>> messages) throws Exception {
    super.addEnvironmentDetails(serviceResponseDocument.getServiceResponse());
}

public abstract class AbstractResponseTransform implements ResponseTransform,
            ApplicationContextAware {

    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;
    private MCSResponseAggregator mcsResponseAggregator;

    public ServiceResponseType addEnvironmentDetails(ServiceResponseType serviceResponse) throws Exception {
        try {
            mcsResponseAggregator = (MCSResponseAggregator) applicationContext
                        .getBean("mcsResponseAggregator");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }
}

public interface ResponseTransform extends Transform {
    public Message<?> handleRequest(Map<String, Message<?>> messages)
            throws Exception;
}

<bean id="mcsResponseAggregator" class="com.company.aggregator.MCSResponseAggregator" scope="request" />
```

Comment: More or less a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411343/request-scoped-beans-in-spring-testing - ignore the bit about test execution listeners.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `WebApplicationContext` to handle beans with: `scope="request"`

I recommend to use stub objects with Spring integration tests and use EasyMock without Spring when you test a class isolated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mocks within the Spring Context:

but that will not solve your problem as it will not make Spring understand scope="request". You can create your [own implementation of the request scope](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-custom), but I'm getting the feeling that you're better off not going through all this trouble.

The easy way out would be to override your request scoped bean in a little test context. You're technically not testing the original context then, but you will be done a lot quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Spring 3.2 comes with support for this. See "[Spring MVC Test Framework](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-framework)"