# How to JUnit test a Spring Bean that contains an @Autowired @Session scoped dependancy

Tags: spring, junit

I've seen the link [Spring Test session scope bean using Junit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136944/spring-test-session-scope-bean-using-junit) that shows how to setup Junit to test @Session scoped beans, but how do I set up a Junit test case to test a Spring bean that has a @Session scoped bean @Autowired into it.

Comment: Solution from this link works with your case too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're testing the behaviour of the spring bean, the easiest way to do this is to mock the object and inject it yourself using ReflectionTestUtils:

```
class SpringBean {
    @Autowired Other other;

    public void method() {
        // ...
    }
}

class SpringBeanTest {
   @Test public void testIt() {
       Other other = new Other();
       SpringBean bean = new SpringBean();
       ReflectionTestUtils.setField(bean, "other", other);
       // test it
   }
}
```