# How to mock a session in Spring 4 Java based config for unit test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, configuration, mocking, spring-4

So I have a session scoped bean and naturally, I'm getting the error you would expect in my unit tests.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Scope registered for scope 'Session'

What is the proper Java based way to mock a session for a unit test?

This was the old way:

[Spring Test session scope bean using Junit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5136944/spring-test-session-scope-bean-using-junit)

The thing is though that I don't need to test a controller. I'm testing a component with a session scoped bean in it. I just need a fake session so that it works.

Comment: A unit test shouldn't need Spring at all. You create a mock bean, you create the component under test and pass it the mock bean as argument, and you call your method to test: `new ComponentUnderTest(mockedBean)`

Comment: The problem is that there's a session scoped bean wired into the object under test. It's just a widget for registering something.

Comment: So create a mock instance of this session scoped bean, and wire it manually in your bean under test. Also create the bean under test manually. You don't need Spring for a unit test. The whole idea of DI is to make unit tests easy. If you posted code, we could tell you how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was this easy :-/

In the test:

```
public void setup() throws Exception {
            ConfigurableBeanFactory factory = (ConfigurableBeanFactory) wac.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
            factory.registerScope("session", new SessionScope());
    }
```

Then you call that before every test that needs it. Could just use @Before if you are using JUnit.

Comment: Afterwards you have to annotate every class with @WebAppConfiguration. You also have to wire in a WebApplicationContext. That is what 'wac' is.