# @Autowired - No qualifying bean found for dependency [javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, controller, autowired

I have a Spring Rest Controller that autowires HttpServletRequest:

```
@Controller
public class AccountSummaryController {
    @Autowired 
    private  HttpServletRequest request;
```

In my pom.xml file:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

In my web.xml file,

```
        <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
      </listener>      
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
          <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/spring-context.xml</param-value>     
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
                <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
                <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <init-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>com.exelon.passport.ws.config.WebConfiguration</param-value>
            </init-param>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>   
      </servlet>  
  <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

And my spring-context.xml file, I tell Spring to annotation-config:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.exelon.passport.ws" />

<mvc:annotation-driven />

<mvc:default-servlet-handler/>

<context:annotation-config />
```

I am using Spring 4.3.3.Release, Tomcat 9 and java 8, Eclipse Neon 2.

The Error:

```
    2017-03-06 09:53:38 DEBUG DispatcherServlet:993 - Could not complete request
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'accountSummaryController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'request'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean found for dependency [javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:569)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:349)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at com.exelon.passport.ws.app.LegalReviewApplicationImpl.setDaos(LegalReviewApplicationImpl.java:102)
    at com.exelon.passport.ws.controller.LegalReviewController.getLegalReviewList(LegalReviewController.java:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at com.exelon.siteminder.authfilter.UserAuthenticatedFilter.doFilter(UserAuthenticatedFilter.java:130)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:745)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean found for dependency [javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1463)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1056)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:566)
    ... 56 more
```

I tried the following trick with no success:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.mock.web.MockServletContext"/>
```

I also tried the solution here non autowired, getting into more errors:

[Spring autowire HttpServletRequest in integration tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17180417/spring-autowire-httpservletrequest-in-integration-tests)

Comment: why do you need autowired HttpServletRequest? You can use it as parameter on any method, maybe i am missing something

Comment: Cralfaro: I just need an instance of HttpServletRequest.  How do you suggest I instantiate it?

Comment: in any mehod inside your controller you can just add as a new parameter (HttpServletRequest request,...) and you will have full access to the request

Comment: On advice, I got of AnnotationConfigureApplicationContext.refresh() code(not showing above), which I think is unrelated to the HttpServletRequest autowired error.  But for some reason, the HttpServletRequest autowired error disappeared and I am able to get the request object. My criticism of Spring's annotation is that it is hard to debug.

Comment: But you dont really need to autowired HttpServletRequest, could you paste one method of your controller GET or POST? I will make you an example, and its easier to understand rather than autowired

Comment: List<ApprovalSummary> approvalSummary = 
    app.getApprovalSummary(request.getRemoteUser(), passport, referenceType, referenceNbr, referenceSubNbr);

Comment: stackoverflow has a size limit on comments.  So I just pasted the main meat in the method.

Comment: also the signature of your method please, add it to your question for a better understanding

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No need to autowire the HttpServletRequest. Here an example of how you could use it.

```
@Controller
public class AccountSummaryController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/yourURL", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView yourMethod(HttpServletRequest request) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("yourView");
        //Here you can access to the request normally
        return mav;
    }
}
```