# Spring singleton issue when using request scope within JUnit

Tags: java, spring, junit, request-mapping

When I run my JUnit tests Spring mistakenly uses the same instance of my JobRunner class each time I try calling the JobConfigurationREST.startJob method.

However, when I call in via a REST web service call, Spring gives me a different instance of the JobRunner class, which is what I want.

How can I tell Spring in my JUnit that we're dealing with a separate request when I call the startJob method?

I have the following code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/jobConfiguration")
public class JobConfigurationREST extends RESTBase {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @RequestMapping(value="/startJob", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces="application/json")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<String> startJob(@RequestBody String jobConfigInfo) {
            JobRunner jr = getJobRunner();
    }

    private JobRunner getJobRunner() {
        return (JobRunner)context.getBean("jobRunner");
    }
}

@Component
@Scope("request")
public class JobRunner{
}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(loader = GenericXmlWebContextLoader.class, locations = {"classpath:/config/spring-config-test.xml"})
public class JobConfigurationRESTTest {

    @Autowired
    private JobConfigurationREST jcREST;

    @Test
    public void testSingletonBug() throws IOException{
        String jobConfig;
        ResponseEntity<String> responseJobStatus = jcREST.startJob(jobConfig);
        ResponseEntity<String> responseJobStatus2 = jcREST.startJob(jobConfig);
    }
}
```

Comment: How have you retreived jobConfig bean in JUnit?

Comment: Autowired. I'll update question.

Comment: Spring 3.2 has provided in built support for request and session scope. Please refer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2411343/request-scoped-beans-in-spring-testing)